# Jquery .each function replacing content

Tags: jquery, ajax, frontend

I'm tired looking solution for this

In HTML

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

Few vars

```
var $content = $(".content");
var $loading_card = '<div class="loading_card"><div class="loader_gif"></div></div>';
```

Then i used Ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, success) {
           $.each(data.DATA, function(i, items) {
             $content.prepend($loading_card);
               $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'url',
                 data: data,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(data, success) {
                   var html_content = '<div class="html"></div>';
                     $loading_card.html(html_content);
                 },
                   error: function() {
                 }
```

Problem is only same html_content is adding in loading card. Loading cards are separate divs and i have to put different data inside each card. Its just overwriting. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that `$loading_card` and `loading_card` are two completely different variables, the same goes for `$content` and `content`. Try dropping the dollarsign from your variable names and see what happens

Comment: Oh my mistake i forget to add $ here

Comment: You have nested calls inside a loop, `html` will overwrite the content each time? If that's not what you want, try `append` instead.

Comment: I have $ sign in my code but i forgot to add here in question.. Problem is same

Comment: Loading cards are separate.. I have to put different data for each card

Comment: This is like what you see when you use Twitter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try bellow updated code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'url',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data, success) {
           var idCounter=1;
           $.each(data.DATA, function(i, items) {
             var loading_cardid="loading_card"+idCounter;
             idCounter+=1;
             var $loading_card = '<div id="'+loading_cardid+'" class="loading_card"></div>';
             $content.prepend($loading_card);
               $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'url',
                 data: data,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function(data, success) {
                   var html_content = '<div class="html">'+data+'</div>';
                     $("#"+loading_cardid).html(html_content);
                 },
                   error: function() {
                 }
```

Comment: This code is not working as i want but gave me an idea of using unique ID :P

Comment: `alert(loading_cardid); $("#"+loading_cardid).html(html_content);` Its just adding only 1 record inside loading card. When i put alert then i saw its just passing same loading_cardid

Comment: This will find element by Id and set html to it. It will not create any issue

Comment: I think thats because we using that inside ajax function.

Comment: But id is same inside Ajax. It needs to be incremented by 1

Comment: In code id counter is already incremented. `idCounter+=1;` So it will generate new id

Comment: Yes you right but thats only working inside each function. Inside second Ajax its just giving same ID ... No increment at all.

Comment: In second ajax we just find element by Id and set html to it.